# How can I make a component disappear and then reappear when needed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a little party system menu thing, and right now I have the "In Queue" component made and it looks like this:

```
import {EventEmitter} from 'events';
import React from 'react';

let ee = new EventEmitter();

class PartyQueueSection extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, ee) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
         timeString: "0H : 0M : 0S",
         timeInterval: function(){},
         hours: 0,
         minutes: 0,
         seconds: 0,
         ee: ee
        }
    }
    startCounter() {
        this.props.setActiveReveal("InQueue");
        let {timeInterval, hours, minutes, seconds, timeString} = this.state;
        hours   = 0;
        minutes = 0;
        seconds = 0;
        timeString = "0H : 0M : 0S";
        timeInterval = setInterval(this.incrementCounter.bind(this), 1000);
        this.setState({timeInterval, hours, minutes, seconds, timeString});
    }
    stopCounter() {
        let {timeInterval} = this.state;
        clearInterval(timeInterval);
        timeInterval = null;
        this.setState({timeInterval});
        $('#PartyApp').foundation('close');
        this.props.setActiveReveal("Other");
    }
    incrementCounter() {
        let {timeString, hours, minutes, seconds} = this.state;
        ++seconds;
        if (seconds >= 60) {
            seconds = 0;
            ++minutes;
        }
        if (minutes >= 60) {
            minutes = 0;
            ++hours;
        }
        timeString = hours + "H : " + minutes + "M : " + seconds + "S";
        this.setState({timeString, hours, minutes, seconds});
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        ee.on('startCounter', this.startCounter.bind(this));
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.stopCounter();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="large-5 columns large-centered text-center">
                    <h2>You are in the queue</h2>
                    <h1>{this.state.timeString}</h1>
                    <br/>
                    <button className="button alert expanded" onClick={this.stopCounter.bind(this)}>Leave Queue</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

$('#enterQueueButton').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   ee.emit('startCounter'); 
});

export default PartyQueueSection;
```

Then the main app component looks like this:

```
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
import React from 'react';
import PartyQueueSection from './PartyQueueSection.jsx';

class PartyApp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            activeReveal: 'InQueue'
        }
    }
    setActiveReveal(name) {
        this.setState({activeReveal: name});
    }
    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            {(() => {
                switch(this.state.activeReveal) {
                    case "InQueue": return <PartyQueueSection setActiveReveal={this.setActiveReveal.bind(this)} />
                };
            })()}
          </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<PartyApp/>, document.getElementById("PartyApp"))
```

But when I click "Leave Queue" and then click "Enter Queue" again I get this message:

`Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.`

So I'm not sure why it unmounts and then when I click the Enter Queue button again it doesn't seem to work the same as it did when I first clicked it:

In a nutshell, click the "Enter Queue" button and everything works fine, I can watch the timer count and everything, then I click "Leave Queue" and then "Enter Queue" again and it gives me the above error

I don't know if it's because I'm using `Event Emitter` so I can make an anchor outside the component (in the navbar) trigger something inside my react component or what. Any information would be great thanks.

Basically I'm trying to make a SPA style view inside of a reveal, I only want the queue to show when the players are in a queue, I only want the party component to show, when the players are in a party, so on so forth

Comment: What component does the `enterQueueButton` live in? Seems like it lives in a separate component than the one where you are declaring the click callback.

Comment: I'm guessing you need to unsubscribe from the 'startCounter' event in componentWillUnmount to prevent your unmounted component from getting events.